# Is there a way to write a LabView VI to do slow conversion on DIO lines?

Tags: physics, labview, circuit, self-starting

[image]

I am not looking for an answer/solution to this problem, rather I am so so lost and just need help figuring out a starting point. Are there any controls or functions in the pallet that definitely need to be used. I know I will need a loop function to do this repeatedly...

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some details not shared in the post above, but here's what's probably be asked:
[image: LVcode]

Answer (score 0):

Is there some broader context for the challenge in the image? Because it doesn't really make much sense as posted.

One thing that leaps out at me is talking about setting the digital value on the DIO lines. In LabVIEW DIO normally refers to a binary output or input, so it can only be 0 or 1. Maybe when they say "lines" they mean to use multiple DIO lines to output the value bit by bit?

It makes me think there's more to the question, for example a diagram showing that multiple DIO lines will be used in that way. Maybe there's another VI that sets the Vguess analog line too.